# anyone know why my jquery wont find newly inserted rows in my html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a dynamic table system where it's possible to add rows by changing row when a row is empty. My problem is that the newly added rows are "invisible" to my event handlers.
These are my event handlers:

```
$('tr td ').on('blur', 'input.autoupdate',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    rid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
});

$('tr td ').on('focus', 'input.autoupdate',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    newid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    check();
});
```

And here is my function to add rows:

```
  var table_row = "<tr><td><input></td></tr>";
  $(table_row).appendTo('#auto_insert');
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is gonna fix your problem:

```
$(document).on('blur', 'tr td input.autoupdate',function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
     event.preventDefault();
     rid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
});
$(document).on('focus', 'tr td input.autoupdate',function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     newid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
     check();
});
```

**problem was:**

your trs and tds are dynamically added, therefor they have no event listener listening for the events happening on them, this is how you can set event listeners on your dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 0):

that was due to the DOM cannot recognize the newly added elements on the page

```
$(document).on('blur', 'tr td input.autoupdate',function(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
 event.preventDefault();
 rid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
});

$(document).on('focus', 'tr td input.autoupdate',function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
 newid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
 check();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're binding the event handlers only to existing `<tr>` and `<td>`. It won't work for the new ones since they were not present when you're script ran.

You need to bind the event handler to an element that exists in `DOM` at the moment.
Bind the handlers to the `<table>` instead, for e.g

```
$('table').on('blur', 'tr td input.autoupdate',function(event){
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using delegated events, which is correct, however you need to make the primary selector an element which is available on DOM load, which your `tr td` elements are not. Try binding to the `table` element instead:

```
$('table')
    .on('blur', 'input.autoupdate', function(event) {
        // your code...
    })
    .on('focus', 'input.autoupdate', function(e) {
        // your code...
    });
```